# php-curl incorrect header size when use proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy, php-curl

This code:

```
$headersSize     = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$responseHeaders = substr($response, 0, $headersSize);
$responseBody    = substr($response, $headersSize);
```

return incorrect size (strlen) of headers, e.g. here:

```
...
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: foo=bar; pat

 ---- curl want split here ---- 

h=/
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

<!DOCTYPE html ...
```

Response can have multiple headers (redirections, continue, etc.). And ofcourse like this isnt work:

```
list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
```

How to correct determine size of headers?

Comment: Might be related to this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63894&edit=1
Please include the PHP and CURL versions you're using.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1204/

`That fix was commit bc6037e which went into curl 7.30.0`

Comment: @AlexanderMP php5.3, but this is required for my application (very old legacy code) and I must fix only without upgrade php version or something.

Comment: Well, it's a bug. Any fix after this bug will be unreliable. Knowing how it works, you can just manually add/subtract to the length of the header by a specific amount, just see how much it's missing.
Or if the proxy is used only for HTML, then you can manually parse the string until you get a line that starts with a HTML tag, which is where your header ends. Sorry, but I don't see a reliable solution other than to fix this bug at the source.

If you can, you can just update curl, libcurl or whatever. Or you can pull that version from git, fix this bug, recompile, if you're version-sensible.

Comment: @AlexanderMP write your comments as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be related to this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63894&edit=1 or http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1204

> That fix was commit bc6037e which went into curl 7.30.0

Anyway, it's a bug. Any fix after this bug will be unreliable.

Knowing how it works, you can just manually add/subtract to the length of the header by a specific amount, just see how much it's missing.

Or if the proxy is used only for HTML, then you can manually parse the string until you get a line that starts with a HTML tag, which is where your header ends.

Sorry, but I don't see a reliable solution other than to fix this bug at the source. If you can, you can just update curl, libcurl or whatever. Or you can pull that version from git, fix this bug, recompile, if you're version-sensible.

Comment: Hmmm!! Proxy server always return first header "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established"? I can try substract this length for correctly slit.